# API works with Postman but fails with Javascript Fetch

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, postman, basic-authentication

I have an API to which I have to post a json body along with basic authentication. This works for me when using postman, however, I can't make it work with Javascript `Fetch` method.

The body of my request is:

```
{
  "plan_id": "plan_AbN7hMdqK8hJ1R",
  "customer_notify": 1,
  "total_count": 6
}
```

**Postman screenshot:**
[image: Header & URL view of postman]

**Postman body field:**
[image]

As you can see, am getting the result without any issue. However, when I do the same in Javascript using the below code, it fails.

```
var url = "https://api.somepay.com/v1/subscriptions"

var body = {
  "plan_id": "plan_AbN7hMdqK8hJ1R",
  "customer_notify": 1,
  "total_count": 6
   }

// handle click 
button.on("click", function(){
  fetch(url, 
    {
      method: 'post',    
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body : JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('user:passkey'),
        'Content-Type' :'application/json',
        'Accept' :'application/json'    
        },
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })

})
```

**I am getting the following error:**

[image]

1.

> POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/subscriptions 401
>   (Unauthorized)

2.

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at (index):89

3.

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://api.apipay.com/v1/subscriptions with MIME type
>   application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Comment: Unless you run your webapp under same domain ,you'll have to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in your server.

Comment: Seems like you are missing a quote (') before 'Basic' in the header section `'Authorization':Basic ' + btoa('user:passkey'),`

Comment: @DeadLock Sorry, was an error that happened while pasting here. Thanks for pointing out. Fixed.

Comment: @MadhanM Let me check from server.

Comment: @esafwan, check your web url, if it different from `http://api.somepay.com`, then you are hitting CORS issue.

Comment: The API was not meant to be called from browser. It was required to be called from backend as it had some sensitive informations. That was the reason it wasn't working.